# serverside onclick but prevent postback in some case

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, server-side

I have following serverside onclick method:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSearch.Text == "" || txtSearch.Text.Length < 4) {
        //NO POSTBACK HERE
    } else {
        Response.Redirect(www.google.be);
    }
}
```

So any advice here? I can't do it the clientside way, because I need to give a server side parameter within the url.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot avoid the postback once you are already executing the server side Click event.

alternatives:

- use a client side function to check and validate and invoke a server side click only in certain cases or return false to avoid it.
- Use UpdatePanel method to enable partial rendering and minimize the impact of the postback. There will still be a postback and whole page lifecycle but minimal page flickering.

in yoour case I think you can simply do everything client side, the code you provided above is easy to write in JQuery.

Comment: But like I said, I need a server side variable that I need to give it within the url as parameter. I Can't do a client side and server side onclick at the same time. Because if I set return false; to client side onclick then my server side onclick doesn't work neither

Comment: but in your case, when txtSearch.Text is null or short you will return false and avoid the postback; only in the other case you will call server side click. Anyway you can even disable the btnSearch button when the textBox does not validate correctly.

Answer (score 2):

why not do it client side?

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" OnClientClick="return validateForm();" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Text="Send" />
```

and have a javascript method:

```
function validateForm(){
    if(document.getElementById('<%= txtSearch.ClientID %>').value == '')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```